# The Generation Time is wrong when pint in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I using phpMyAdmin 4.4.14 in Win7+Chrome and MySQL 5.6 in Linux.

My timezone is +8

The `date` command in Linux returns a correct date and time.

When I issue `select now()` inside the phpMyAdmin, the date and time is correct.

But, when I print the result, the time value in the `Generation Time` is wrong.

Look like that the `Generation Time` does not do a +8 to the hour.

How to fix ?

Cheers,
Alvin SIU

Comment: what is Generation Time?

Comment: When you click the Print View in phpMyAdmin, it will create a new TAB in Chrome.  The TAB is a clean HTML page with a `Print` button at the bottom. In this HTML page, the first line is `SQL Result`. The 2nd line is `Host: localhost`.  The 3rd line is `Database: XXXXXXXX`. The 4th line is `Generation Time: Feb 25, 2016 at 07:45 AM`.  The 5th line is `Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.4.xx.x / MySQL 5.6.xx`.  The actual time, according to my watch, should be 15:45 in the afternoon, not 07:45 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print view is done via PHP script, so the issue is in PHP, not in MySQL. In order to change this timestamp, you need to open php.ini and to change/add `date.timezone` variable with desired value:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"
```

All available timezones can be found here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php